# Router link not set to active upon navigating to new page - Angular 2

Tags: angular, navbar, angular2-routing

I have this website with a NavBarComponent. There is a new instance of the exact same NavBarComponent for every page in the website.

So when I click on a link in the navBarComponent, it goes to the page, but since the page has a new navBarComponent, the corresponding link in the NavBar is not active. I need it to be active.

Here are some images to show what I mean:

Homepage:

[image]

click on "find" and not active in new page:

[image]

click on find again, and since it is the same page so the same NavigationBar, it is now active.

[image]

What is the best way to make the "find" link active on the first time clicking the "find" link?

This is the code for the navBarComponent which is shared between all webpages:

HTML template:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-fixed-top text-uppercase">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <button     class="navbar-toggler hidden-md-up pull-xs-right" 
                    type="button" 
                    data-toggle="collapse" 
                    data-target="#nav-content">
                    &#9776;
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" [routerLink]="['/']" routerLinkActive="active">the vegan repository</a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-sm" id="nav-content">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-xs-right">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/find']" routerLinkActive="active">find</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/add']" routerLinkActive="active">add</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">login</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">sign up free</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

css template:

```
.navbar-toggler {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7); }

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7); }

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus,
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
  color: #FFF; }

nav {
  background-color: #fc4747; }

a {
  cursor: pointer; }
```

typescript component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
    selector: 'navbar',
    templateUrl: 'app/shared/navbar.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/shared/navbar.component.css'],
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class NavbarComponent { }
```

Comment: This way it is hard to say anything. Why don't you just check DOM object. Check when you press find link, does it add class='active' in DOM or not?

Comment: @micronyks yes but then it creates a new navbar for the new page that loads and it doesnt have class="active"